# Accessing a static property of a view model is null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

in my app I need to call a method in my main view model from a sub settings view model to change a tab control in the main view.  Basically its a list of viewsmodels in a tab control.  The settings viewmodel has checkboxes to turn tabs on or off.

Anyway, I setup a static property in the main viewmodel of the instance.   In my settings viewmodel constructor I get a null response but if I retrieve the instance on each checkbox property change it works.  Seems like a timing issue on when the instances are created. Is there an event or something that can tell me when the main viewmodel instance isn't null?

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type skyTelescope:SkyTelescopeVM}">
        <skyTelescope:SkyTelescopeV />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type rotator:RotatorVM}">
         <rotator:RotatorView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type focuser:FocuserVM}">
          <focuser:FocuserView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type settings:SettingsVM}">
        <settings:SettingsV />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Can't you make your sub settings viewmodel a child of the main window viewmodel?

Comment: How would I do that?  Currently Settings is loaded from the main view as a user control.  Isn't this considered a child?

Comment: If you used viewmodel first then it'd be templated out from a viewmodel in your mainwindowviewmodel. So you could pass anything you liked and you'd know your viewmodel was definitely fully instantiated because it is controlling the data the usercontrol needs.

Comment: Added to OP what my Main View is doing, then I just bind to a selected viewmodel based on radio buttons. Sorry I'm so naive about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot to learn with wpf and the mvvm approach is very different from event driven code.

Your markup looks like you're doing viewmodel first... or something like that.
If you have a MainWindowViewModel exposes say a SubVM property.

Bind SubVM to the content property of a contentcontrol in mainwindow.
Set SubVM to an instance of a viewmodel such as SettingsVM.
This is then templated out in the view using the matching datatemplate.
You see a SettingsV appear.
The datacontext of SettingsV is your SubVM.
Bind controls in SettingsV to properties in SubVM and the values can transfer between them.
That allows you to control when you instantiate SettingsVM in MainWindowViewModel.
You therefore "know" whether you have an instance of it or not.
You can cache instances of viewmodels in a dictionary.
Use a type as your key and you can instantiate one if you don't have it in your dictionary, then re-use it if you wanted to retain state.

You can make MainWindow instantiate MainWindowViewModel by defining it's datacontext in xaml.

```
  <Window.DataContext>
      <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
```

With viewmodel first there's an oddity with the way templating works. If you wanted to reset (unbound) view state then you need to force the re-templating by setting your SubVM property null first.
This command takes a Type as a parameter

```
    private RelayCommand<Type> navigateCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Type> NavigateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return navigateCommand
              ?? (navigateCommand = new RelayCommand<Type>(
                vmType =>
                {
                    CurrentViewModel = null;
                    CurrentViewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(vmType);
                }));
        }
    }
```

Obviously, this doesn't stash any instance of a vm away in a dictionary, it's just instantiating every time.

Comment: Your explanation comes very close to my setup. Adding in the Window.DataContext keeps putting VS2017 into a no response state.  Maybe this is the oddity you refereed to.

Comment: No that isn't. Are you sure it's the viewmodel rather than view?  Because the latter would infinite loop.

Comment: conflict with d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance main:MainWindowVM, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" but its still null in my settingsvm constructor.

Comment: Remove the designercontext. And how can the main mainwindowviewmodel possibly ever be null if it is that which is the only thing instantiates subvm? The former has to be instantiated.

Comment: You can't say that, it was my question :)  starting to think it has to do with MaterialDesignThemes.  Somehow it must be creating the settingsvm first.

Comment: ahha...  I'm loading settingsvm in the constructor of the mainwindowvm.  So mainwindowvm isn't finished?